# IP addresses from same network?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I have a client who was falsely accused of a crime.  In order to show that he didn't do it, I need to show that the following IP addresses were likely sent from the same network/person:

209.85.218.46,
209.85.167.42,
209.85.160.178,
209.85.217.45

They are similar, but not the same.  What do these numbers mean?  Do the first two numbers (209.85) indicate something about location or network? We believe the true wrongdoer is lying and this may prove it.  Please help.  Thanks

Comment: "[Understand TCP/IP addressing and subnetting basics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcpip-addressing-and-subnetting)" may be a good place to start.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Unix or Linux

Answer (score 2):

All 4 addresses belong to Google and are from one common range of `209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255`. This information is obtained from the IP Whois service, e.g. https://iplocation.io/ip-whois-lookup.

Unfortunately, the range is very large and there is nothing to prove that the same person had to use them.

Reverse DNS records assign the following names to addresses:

- 209.85.160.178 = mail-qt1-f178.google.com.
- 209.85.167.42 = mail-lf1-f42.google.com.
- 209.85.218.46 = mail-ej1-f46.google.com.
- 209.85.217.45 = mail-vs1-f45.google.com.

For further analysis, it would be necessary to obtain much more details, for example, from the Internet headers of e-mail messages, i.e. from the source code of the e-mails that were sent from the addresses, I assume.

Google, as a provider, should keep a record of who used what address when. (This is the case for providers in Europe. I don't know the situation in the US.) Based on a police investigation and a court order, he could provide details of the user who used the addresses at that time.

With a few exceptions, addresses are gradually used by different users over time.

**Here is the detail about IP address range:**

```
NetRange:       209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
CIDR:           209.85.128.0/17
NetName:        GOOGLE
NetHandle:      NET-209-85-128-0-1
Parent:         NET209 (NET-209-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:
Organization:   Google LLC (GOGL)
RegDate:        2006-01-13
Updated:        2012-02-24
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/209.85.128.0



OrgName:        Google LLC
OrgId:          GOGL
Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
City:           Mountain View
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94043
Country:        US
RegDate:        2000-03-30
Updated:        2019-10-31
Comment:        Please note that the recommended way to file abuse complaints are located in the following links.
Comment:
Comment:        To report abuse and illegal activity: https://www.google.com/contact/
Comment:
Comment:        For legal requests: http://support.google.com/legal
Comment:
Comment:        Regards,
Comment:        The Google Team
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/GOGL


OrgTechHandle: ZG39-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Google LLC
OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-253-0000
OrgTechEmail:  arin-contact@google.com
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ZG39-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE5250-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-253-0000
OrgAbuseEmail:  network-abuse@google.com
OrgAbuseRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE5250-ARIN
```

Comment: Just a note to add to the excellent info you posted, @digibat - the fact that a Mountain View California address is listed in the info does not mean these IP addresses are used in California (they might have been, or might not have been).  It's just the address of Google's headquarter office.

Comment: [Sotto Voce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/531636/sotto-voce), thank you for the answer accuracy improvement.